# Validate E-Mail with a Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, email

I want to validate an E-Mail Address with a regular expression in Java. The format of the E-Mail Address is

> firstname.lastname@company.xx

The E-Mail address don't contains upper case letters or numbers. The only expression I have is this

```
([a-z]+(?:[.][a-z]+)*)
```

but that didn't help me. It is important, that the expression looks for the "." between the firstname and lastname.

It would be nice, if someone could help me with this expression.

Comment: @sleske not quite since in this case the email format is more restrictive

Comment: @Stephan: With a basic understanding of regex, you should be able to modify the linked answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `[a-z]+\.[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,3}`

```
String text = "firstname.lastname@company.xx";
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+@[a-z]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}").matcher(text);
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
m1.find();
System.out.println(m1.group(0));
```

Comment: Np mate, I'm glad I could help :)